# Java - Better model to save objects (Collection)

Tags: java, collections

Consider the below case

1) I need to save objects of Location class (defined in my app) along with
   all the User (defined in my app) objects as collection as shown below

```
HashMap<Location, Collection<Person>>
```

And the data is stored like below in HashMap (as objects, i am mentioning name for explanation)

```
Location1 - User1, User2, User3
Location2 - User2, User3
Location3 - User1
```

Now in the above example, in hashmap redundant copies of User1, User2 and User3 are stored inside each Location. is this correct method to save data of one to many relation in a collection?

Comment: clarify what you mean by "save"? is this stored on disk after your program closes..?

Comment: I mean to say that the User1, User2 etc., are saved in the collection object within HashMap.. if this is just a reference and ont consume memory as specified by @Arjun Rao.. then its ok to keep this format.

Comment: I see. Well, check out my answer and the other posters. That may help. It is OK to keep your format but it may be useful to consider additional possibilities, such as AmitD's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "Redundancy". All the hashmap stores are references to the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The information contained within Person1 is only stored once, unless you did something that explicitly made a copy of that object (say, by using the clone() method, if implemented)

Normally, adding an object like person1 to more than one collection should not make a whole new object identical to the first and put it in the collection.  What is going on is that there are multiple *references* to the person object being saved in different collections.  Each reference is tiny compared to the size of a whole new object, and while you might have multiple references to the same object, the information managed by that Person object (such as name, email, etc) is only stored once.

Therefore:  What you are doing with the Collections is fine, it does not create multiple copies of your objects.

(There are no pointers in java, but if you have ever studied a language that allows them, the idea is similar in that multiple smaller pointers can point to a single large object)

Answer (score 2):

A `Person` is a reference to an object.  When you pass it to a method like `add()` or `put()` you are giving it a copy of the references (which is typically 32-bit even on 64-bit JVMs)

This means your collection can have "redundant" copies of the same reference, but given you want that reference in multiple places, I don't see a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `HashMap`.You can have `User` contained in `Location` class as it suits your requirement perfectly.

```
public class Location {
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return users.add(user);
    }

    public boolean remove(User user) {
        return users.remove(user);
    }

    public Set<User> getAll() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Location {
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public boolean addUser(User user) {
        return users.add(user);
    }

    public boolean remove(User user) {
        return users.remove(user);
    }

    public Set<User> getAll() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(users);
    }
}
```

Identical to Amit's answer just keep a `Set<User>` associated with your `Location`. Then, you should additionally use an `ArrayList<Location>` to store all of your `Locations`. As Arjun has pointed out, there is no redundancy (duplicated User Objects). When will there be no redundancy? When each `User` Object is only created once, and then added to multiple Collections. This is because the *reference* to the `User` is actually being stored in the Collection. That is what is meant in Java by "pass a reference by value". In a List's add method, for example, you may call `add(User)` but what Java does in the background is passes a copy of the reference (think memory location) of the `User` Object to the List. So the List doesn't actually store the User Object directly, however, it is located in memory somewhere.

Comment: what is the difference between your answer and @AmitDs answer??

Comment: @code13 Explanation for one? I explained pass by reference. Amit's answer offered no explanation. Also, the important detail of storing each Location in a shared List. If you don't, they will be garbage collected and not be usable by other code. OP is obviously a beginner so I don't see how it is useful to give him working code and say "do it like that!" without offering explantion.